# PHP script for downloading files with utf-8 characters in the names

Tags: php, download

I have files named in foreign characters, that I have uploaded after encoding the names using utf8_encode(). But now, when I m trying to download them using readfile(), they give "not found" errors.

I have pasted the code below. I think the problem lies with some header I have defined. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
<?php

    ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
    ini_set('mbstring.http_input','auto');
    ini_set('mbstring.http_output','UTF-8');
    ini_set('mbstring.detect_order','auto');
    ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

    $url = "http://filedownload.s3.amazonaws.com/cÃ©nari.txt";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($url));
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.utf8_decode($url));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($url);

?>
```

I have also attached the file that gets downloaded on running this code.

I m using PHP for download instead of other methods in S3 cos all these files are public and the only way I can keep them hidden is by hiding the url.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to urlencode() the name:

```
$url = "http://filedownload.s3.amazonaws.com/" . urlencode("cÃ©nari.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had tried it earlier but had by mistake, urlencoded the whole url instead.

Comment: If this is the solution you're using, please mark it as such.